# where do you host your project site with Bamboo CI?

Tags: maven, cmake, bamboo

When you build a project e.g. with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) one gets the project site generated by doing `mvn site` or similarly using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) one generates the [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) documentation (assuming the correct configuration in [CMakeLists.txt](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html)) with `make doc`. Once I get this executed as a Task in Bamboo; where can I deploy such websites? I have already several Web Servers running in my CI environment: JIRA, Bamboo, Stash and Fisheye. I'd prefer not having to run another Web Server just to host the project static HTML documentation and sites.

Anyone have any ideas how this can be published? e.g. maybe a project report as part of Bamboo? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Company I work for does two things:

1. We Run a Web Server with all our documentation on it that gets updated whenever a build finishes. (docs.my-company.com)
2. We zip up the documentation from the build and make it available as a artifact thats downloadable.

One solution for you is if you already run say Bamboo at a domain like `build.my-company.com/` you could setup an Apache Location called like `build-docs` that contains all your generated build docs from the Bamboo builds.

This lets you double up on a Web Server without creating yet another web server.

Comment: Indeed this would be a nice way to go, just for completeness I might need a post-install script to add such location after getting Bamboo updates. Would there be a way to introduce a convenience permanent link to the project website in JIRA, Bamboo or Fisheye?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be include a link to the documentation in a README in the Source Control Repository, you could then make the README an artifact in Bamboo. Fisheye you could just open the link in the README. JIRA you could add it to the Project Summary. Alternatively you could create an atlassian plugins that contains a menu with links to all the various documentations. (Should be a pretty bare plugin).